# Android - Build a push notification that pops up twice a week

Tags: android, android-notifications

i want to build a push notification that prompts the device 2 times in
a week and direct it into a certain activity. can you show me on how to and what time function or algorithm should i use to implement this? thanks

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Home Seek ")
    .setContentText("View nearby available listings near you");

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
...
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: User alarm manager and setting two alarms for different times in a week.

Comment: show me how to do it

Comment: ok let me assemble code for you.... have a look to my answer

Comment: waiting... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to set the notification time for your notification ...you will be notified when app is closed as well.

```
public class AlarmTiming {
static AlarmManager alarmManager;
static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
static DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;

static String[] pieces;
/*..duration time for alarm to notify you every 3 days ...
mean twice in a week.. you just have to set it again when notification is reached/alarmed
for the next duration*/
static int alarmDuration = 72;
public static void SetTwiceNotification(Context c) {
    String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    pieces = formattedDate.split(":");
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar)calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(pieces[0])+alarmDuration);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]));
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    setAlarm(calSet,c);
}
private static void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal,Context c ) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmBroadcaster.class);
    //..
    pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 1, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Here is the broadcast receiver class to receive notification...

```
public class AlarmBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;
String typeFlag;
int flagId;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    createNotification(context);
    AlarmTiming.SetTwiceNotification(context);
}

public void createNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class),0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifi_righter_logo);

    //...
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    String[] events = {"You are reminded to review your APP"};
    // Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(" Notification !");

    // Moves events into the expanded layout
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }
    // Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
    builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: let me know if you have any query ...!

Comment: What you mean query?

Comment: mean ... if you have any question about code ... if you are unable to understand what any function is doing :)

Comment: Okay analyzing it ill put this to test later